# Chat error page has old style topbar

Tags: bug, chat, top-bar

When something goes wrong in chat, you're dumped to an [error page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/).  At the top of the page isn't the current topbar, it's the old topbar.

Can we get some new-style topbar love on the error page?

Comment: Heh, didn't notice it before.

Comment: @nicael sure, it's very rare to reach the chat error page - personally never happened to me.